# How to apply localization with React and Laravel inertia?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I am using React with Inertia and laravel.
I want to add multiple languages (Translation,localization) to my website.
I used mcamara Before as backend localization with blade.
The question is How to make mcamara interact with React?
Is there more efficent way to do that?
I know I can use i18next to make localization in the front, but I want it in the back
because user will change language rarely, it doesn't need to be dynamic, fast or anything else. It's OK if we reload the whole app.
I am really confused to apply that.
Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead react-localization-with-i18next https://blog.logrocket.com/react-localization-with-i18next/